# Is GeoCoding has limited access to the locations in flutter apps?

Tags: flutter

I'm using Geolocator and Geocoding in my flutter app inorder to get the the location of the user. but i saw this in the documentation in the Geocoding

> This plugin uses the free Geocoding services provided by the iOS and Android platforms. This means that there are restrictions to their use. More information can be found in the Apple documentation for iOS and the Google documentation for Android. When a PlatformException(IO_ERROR, ...) gets thrown, most of the times it means that the rate limit has been reached.

is that mean that we have only limited requests for the users ?

Comment: yes indeed, it means there is a fixed quota of max number of requests for a given time

Comment: @pskink hello Thanks for your response, ok but for the geolocator there's no limit for using its api, only for the geocoding there is right ?

Comment: i dont know, you need to check your docs